# How to use function object as callback to invoke member functions (handlers) in an object?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, glfw

I wanted to create a `window_callback` function object that I could use in `glfwSet[...]Callback()` functions. It is supposed to find a `window` in the `inline static std::unordered_map<GLFWwindow*, window&> windows_by_handles` by its `GLFWwindow* handle` and than call its appropriate handler. This is my current code:

```
template <typename... Args>
class window_callback
{
    typedef void(window::*member_func_t)(Args...);
    member_func_t func;
public:
    window_callback(member_func_t func_) :
        func(func_)
    {
    }

    void operator() (GLFWwindow* HWND, Args... args)
    {
        try
        {
            window& wnd = windows_by_handles.at(HWND);
            (wnd.*func)(args...); //error E0165
        }
        catch (const std::out_of_range&)
        {
            std::cerr << "Detected callback for unknown window\n";
        }
    }

    operator decltype(&(operator()))() { return &operator(); }
};
```

The `window_callback` objects are created in the following manner (inside the `window` class):

```
inline static window_callback<int, int> resize_callback{ &on_resize };
inline static window_callback<double, double> mouse_movement_callback{ &on_mouse_moved };
inline static window_callback<double, double> scroll_callback{ &on_scrolled };
```

Then, they are bound with `glfwSet[...]Callback()` functions like this (inside the `window` class constructor):

```
glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(handle, resize_callback);
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(handle, mouse_movement_callback);
glfwSetScrollCallback(handle, scroll_callback);
```

The given code doesn't compile. It gives the following errors when compiling in Visual Studio 2019 (using C++17). The first 2 errors happen on the user-defined conversion operator declaration:

- C2833 'operator type' is not a recognized operator or type
- C2059 syntax error: 'newline'
- C2664 `GLFWframebuffersizefun glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(GLFWwindow *,GLFWframebuffersizefun)`: cannot convert argument 2 from `window::window_callback<int,int>` to `GLFWframebuffersizefun`
- C2664 `GLFWcursorposfun glfwSetCursorPosCallback(GLFWwindow *,GLFWcursorposfun)`: cannot convert argument 2 from `window::window_callback<double,double>` to `GLFWcursorposfun`
- C2664 `GLFWscrollfun glfwSetScrollCallback(GLFWwindow *,GLFWscrollfun)`: cannot convert argument 2 from `window::window_callback<double,double>` to `GLFWscrollfun`

The problematic part is the conversion from the `window_callback` type to the appropriate function pointer types. What should be changed to make this code work or what is an alternate solution that will work in the same manner?

Comment: _"conversion from the window_callback type to the appropriate function pointer types"_ - You cannot convert a class instance (or a class method) to a function pointer. You need a static method or free function.

Comment: @MaxLanghof What do you mean by "I can't"? If I define a conversion operator I can convert to any type I want. Or no...?

Comment: Your `operator decltype(whatever)()` still returns a `decltype(whatever)`, which will be a member function pointer (which `glfw` won't accept).

Comment: @MaxLanghof How does `std::less` (and similar) work, than?

Comment: `std::less` won't work with something that expects a function pointer. `std::less` is a struct with `operator()` (the call operator) overloaded, which works just fine with all the _templated_ standard library functions (which don't care if you pass a function pointer or a functor struct). Unless I am mistaken, `glfw` is not templated and only accepts function pointers as callbacks. Capture-less lambdas can be converted to function pointers, but your own functor structs cannot.

Comment: `std::less` has no state. You can simply default construct one and call the operator of that.

Comment: Is using `glfwSetWindowUserPointer`/`glfwGetWindowUserPointer` an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use function object as callback to invoke member functions (handlers) in an object?
>
> that I could use in glfwSet[...]Callback() functions.

Glfw does not accept member function pointers as callback functions, nor does it accept function objects.

You can only register function pointers. Function pointers cannot point to non-static member functions. The function call operator overload of a function object is also a member function.

You need to write a non-member function (or you can use a static member function if you prefer) that wraps the call to the member function (or a function object if you prefer).

Example:

```
struct C {
    void window_size(GLFWwindow*, int, int);
};

auto window_size_callback = [](GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h) {
    C c;
    c.window_size(window, w, h);
}; // a non-capturing lambda can be converted to a function pointer
   // you can use a named function if you prefer

glfwSetWindowSizeCallback(window, window_size_callback);
```

But, presumably you need access to some particular instance of the class (or function object), rather than a default constructed one. After all, why use a non-static member function if that wasn't the case. To achieve that, you need some way of passing a reference to that object into the callback.

The way documented by GLFW is:

> Each window has a user pointer that can be set with `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and queried with `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`. This can be used for any purpose you need and will not be modified by GLFW throughout the life-time of the window.

If all of your callbacks are to be called on a single object, using this is simple:

```
C c;
glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window, &c);

auto window_size_callback = [](GLFWwindow* window, int w, int h) {
    C* cptr = static_cast<C*>(glfwSetWindowUserPointer(window));
    assert(c);
    cptr->window_size(window, w, h);
};
```

Unfortunately, GLFW API doesn't appear to support callback specific user data. If you need different objects for different callbacks, you could possibly use your own map from callback to object, but that's not quite as simple as the example above.

Furthermore, be very careful to keep the object alive at least as long as the window is alive so that callbacks don't get called on a dangling pointer.